# Save ID from dropdown list into other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with fields and one dropdown list. The data from the dropdown list comes out the table: categorie.  (fields are: catID, catName)

When I select a categorie from the drop down list and fill all the other input fields, it saves all the input fields and only the catName from the categorie table into the tabel: event.
How can I also save the selected catID from the categorie table into the event table?

Can someone helm me out here?

Regards, Benny

```
    <?php require '../Connections/localhost.php'; ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['newEvent'])) {

        session_start();
        $eventName = $_POST['SelCatName'];
        $eventSDate = $_POST['Event-StartDate'];
        $eventSTime = $_POST['Event-StartTime'];
        $eventEDate = $_POST['Event-EndDate'];
        $eventETime = $_POST['Event-EndTime'];
        $eventDescription = $_POST['Event-Description'];
        $catID = $_POST["catID"];

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO event (eventName, eventSDate, eventSTime, eventEDate, eventETime, eventDescription, catID)Values('{$eventName}', '{$eventSDate}', '{$eventSTime}', '{$eventEDate}', '{$eventETime}', '{$eventDescription}', '{$catID}')");


    header('Location: eventOK.php');
    }
?>



<form action="" method="post" name="RegisterForm" id="RegisterForm">

    <div class="FormElement">

       <select name="SelCatName" class="TField" id="SelCatName">
            <option selected="selected" id="0">--Selecteer een categorie--</option>         
                    <?php 
                        $GetAllCategories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM categorie");
                        while ($ViewAllCategories = mysqli_fetch_array($GetAllCategories)){
                    ?>  
            <option id="<?php echo $ViewAllCategories['catID']; ?>"><?php echo $ViewAllCategories ['catName']; ?> </option>   

                <?php } ?>       

        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in `<option id="id"></option>`
if you wanna take value from select child.

you must change id to value="" or you must add value="id" proper.

change your select box block completely like below..

```
<select name="SelCatName" class="TField" id="SelCatName">
<option selected="selected" id="0">--Selecteer een categorie--</option>         
<?php 
$GetAllCategories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM categorie");
while ($ViewAllCategories = mysqli_fetch_array($GetAllCategories)){
?>  
<option value="<?PHP echo $ViewAllCategories['catID'].'-'.$ViewAllCategories['catName']; ?>"> <?PHP echo $ViewAllCategories['catName']; ?></option>   

<?php } ?>       
</select>
```

and a tip for mysql query... to the best of one's ability don't use `"select * from"` use it if you dont need to all colums better than "*"

```
$con->query("SELECT catID, catName FROM categorie");
```

PHP file

```
    <?php require '../Connections/localhost.php'; ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['newEvent'])) {

        session_start();

        //$eventName = $_POST['SelCatName'];
        $eventSDate = $_POST['Event-StartDate'];
        $eventSTime = $_POST['Event-StartTime'];
        $eventEDate = $_POST['Event-EndDate'];
        $eventETime = $_POST['Event-EndTime'];
        $eventDescription = $_POST['Event-Description'];
        $catIDs = $_POST["SelCatName"];
        $catID = explode("-", $catIDs);

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO event (eventName, eventSDate, eventSTime, eventEDate, eventETime, eventDescription, catID)Values('{$catID[1]}', '{$eventSDate}', '{$eventSTime}', '{$eventEDate}', '{$eventETime}', '{$eventDescription}', '{$catID[0]}')");


    header('Location: eventOK.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Now, only the catID is stored in the table event. 
I also need that the catName will be stored in the event table unther the field  eventName.

Comment: I update my anser please check it. I use explode for getting 2 value from one option...

Comment: Now nothing happens, the catID or catName are not stored in the table.

Comment: Im so sorry I missed this line. please change $_POST["catID"] to $_POST['SelCatName'] I will update answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.
It works exactly like I want. ;-)

Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

to me you are missusing the attribute of ID, Replace the ID for value: your option tag already have the id and name

```
<select name="SelCatName" class="TField" id="SelCatName">
```

your code will be:

```
<?php 
    $GetAllCategories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM categorie");
    while ($ViewAllCategories = mysqli_fetch_array($GetAllCategories)){
?>  
    <option value="<?php echo $ViewAllCategories['catID']; ?>"> <?php echo $ViewAllCategories ['catName']; ?> </option>   

<?php } ?>
```

Therefore you will find your post as only SelCatName = (numerical ID)
Now, if you need that the list of the catID and catName stores to the next page you can re-run your query in the next page and store them in an array.